# Как решить проблему постоянной потери связи с интернетом на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Работаю с одноплатником Beaglebone, на нем установлена Ubuntu. При включении системы интернет не работает, после команды `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`
связь появляется, но буквально на минуту, после чего опять исчезает. Повторные действия вызывают такой же результат.

Как это исправить, сделать связь стабильной, те же настройки прописывал для raspberry все работает идеально, в чем проблема?

Вот данные ping

```
ping -c 3 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (64.233.165.104) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2034ms
```

Вот данные interface

```
auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameserver 10.10.8.5
dns-nameserver 10.10.8.6
# The primary network interface
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

        address 10.10.2.183
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.10.2.6
        dns-nameserver 10.10.8.5
        dns-nameserver 10.10.8.6
```

лог до перезагрузки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

лог после перезагрузки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
потом возращается в первое состояние

Comment: А почему настройки именно такие и адрес именно 10.10.2.183?

Comment: Сделайте так: 1) Выполняем команду *tail -f /var/log/messages &* 2) выполняем команду *sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart* 3) Всё, что выдастся на экран после этой команды внимательно изучаем, пытаясь найти слово *Error* 4) Если ситуация не прояснилась - этот вывод перекладываем сюда.

Comment: Судя по логу, у вас там connman (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ConnMan). Вероятно, его мало интересует содержимое `interfaces`. Варианта виду два: 1) конфигурировать сеть через него; 2) снести его (только осторожно).